# Clearing nested data

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a `map` data like this

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> mydata;
```

How does the function `mydata.clear();` work?
Does it clear the items in the `vector<int>` too?
Does it need to clear the `vector` items first and then clear the map?

Comment: Your map stores the vector by value, so when you call clear(), those vectors will disappear (their destructors will be called). You don't need to clean them manually first.

Answer (score 2):

`mydata.clear()` clears the data in the `map`. The `map` as you have defined it stores the `std::vector<int>` *by value*; the value nature ensures that the destructor of the vector is called and its content and allocated memory are also cleared.

From the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/clear);

> Removes all elements from the container.
>   Invalidates any references, pointers, or iterators referring to contained elements.

The [`vector`'s destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/%7Evector) in turn manages its resources;

> Destructs the container. The destructors of the elements are called and the used storage is deallocated. Note, that if the elements are pointers, the pointed-to objects are not destroyed.

The rule of thumb here is that *the container will manage the container's resources; memory, size, allocations etc. and the values in the container need to manage their resources* in turn. This approach and technique to resource management is commonly known as [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) and is considered by many to be idiomatic C++.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of `clear()` [is defined that way](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/clear/):

> **Clear content** 
>   Removes all elements from the map container (which are destroyed), leaving the container with a size of 0.

Your map uses plain `vectors`, not pointers or references to them. These vectors themselves store plain `ints` that do not require (and wouldn't support) manual unallocation.

So when you will call `mydata.clear()`, the `vectors` the `map` contains will be properly destroyed, and so will their content.